# Counting the number of elements with the same class in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I count dynamically generate elements with the same class in jquery?
I found a similar question, but unfortunately it didn't work.
[jQuery counting elements by class; what is the best way to implement this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this)

I did something like this which I based from the answers:

```
$('.capital_class').live('blur', function(){

alert($(this).length);
});
```

The elements with a class of capital_class are dynamically generated. But I always get the length of 1, whenever I blur. How do I get this correctly?

Comment: Try use `.capital_class` instead of `this` in alert.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change the alert to this:

```
alert($('.capital_class').length);
```

Remember the event is called on a single element so `this` is just a single element -- you have to have jQuery query the dom after the event happens.  (The first query just sets up the live handling to create the event handlers.)

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$('.capital_class').live('blur', function(){

alert($('.capital_class').length);
});
```

`this` in the function refers to the event target, and when you do `$(this).length`, it returns 1 because that element doesn't have any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you need in this case, but in order to make it more dynamic in case you have multiple classes, and want to ensure that *all* classes match, you can do this:

```
$('.capital_class').live('blur', function(){

    var classes_selector = '.' + $.trim(this.className).replace(/\s+/g,'.');
    alert($( classes_selector ).length);

});
```

You're basically replacing all instances of one or more consecutive spaces in the `className` property with a single `.` character. This is because the [`class-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) is capable of selecting based on matching *all* classes provided.

It also uses the [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method to get rid of any leading/trailing space.

Now if you add and remove additional classes to your element that received the event, it will always only match those elements that have all the same classes.

---

If instead you want to match all elements that have *any one* of the classes that the original element does, then do this:

```
$('.capital_class').live('blur', function(){

    var classes_selector = '.' + $.trim(this.className).replace(/\s+/g,',.');
    alert($( classes_selector ).length);

});
```

This simply adds a comma to the selector to separate the classes, creating a [`multiple-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).