# jQuery count number of divs with a certain class?

Tags: jquery, html, count

Considering something like this;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How would I, using jQuery (or plain JS, if it's shorter - but I doubt it) count the number of divs with the "item" class? In this example, the function should return 5, as there are 5 divs with the item class.

Thanks!

Comment: try $("div.item").length or $("div.item").size()

Comment: this should help you:
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this

Comment: size() is deprecated stick to length

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can use the jquery [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property

```
var numItems = $('.item').length;
```

Comment: ...I think it should be $('div.item') to count divs with that class (and not include any other kind of element with the .item class).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed! I'll accept your answer as soon as the time limit is over!

Comment: @jjmontes that's true. Of course you can use any selector.. but it depends on how specifc the OP wants to get. For example `$('div.wrapper div.item')` would be even closer.

Comment: After i get the **length**, how to set an array for every div with that class ?, for example i want to input text with `.html()` in first or second div item.

Answer (score 21):

For better performance you should use:

```
var numItems = $('div.item').length;
```

Since it will only look for the `div` elements in `DOM` and will be quick.

**Suggestion:** using `size()` instead of `length` property means one extra step in the processing since `SIZE()` uses `length` property in the function definition and returns the result.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what the difference in time/performance in using `div.item` instead of `.item` would be, of course this would be dependent on how big the document is but generally speaking I'm curious to know if it makes a major difference

Answer (score 14):

You can use jQuery.children property.

```
var numItems = $('.wrapper').children('div').length;
```

for more information refer http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 3):

And for the plain js answer if anyone might be interested;

```
var count = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
```

Cheers.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Answer (score 2):

I just created this js function using the jQuery size function http://api.jquery.com/size/

```
function classCount(name){
  alert($('.'+name).size())
}
```

It alerts out the number of times the class name occurs in the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .test {
                background: #ff4040;
                color: #fff;
                display: block;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test"> one </div>
        <div class="test"> two </div>
        <div class="test"> three </div>
        <div class="test"> four </div>
        <div class="test"> five </div>
        <div class="test"> six </div>
        <div class="test"> seven </div>
        <div class="test"> eight </div>
        <div class="test"> nine </div>
        <div class="test"> ten </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //get total length by class
            var numItems = $('.test').length;
            //get last three count
            var numItems3=numItems-3;         


            var i = 0;
            $('.test').each(function(){
                i++;
                if(i>numItems3)
                {

                    $(this).attr("class","");
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have to get total number of class, and then if you can get last 3 element remove so get total - 3 then using each loop and condition of last last 3 record remove class.

Answer (score 0):

can count child divs like this

```
let number_of_child_divs =  $('.wrapper').children('.item').length;
```

outout : 5

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to count for table tr elements but in my case I was needed count should be updated in real time. Here is my solution to get tr count real time.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Get initial number of rows
   var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
   $('#rowCount').text(`Total rows: ${rowCount}`);

   // Handle rows being added
   $('#myTable').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
      rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
      $('#rowCount').text(`Total rows: ${rowCount}`);
   });

   // Handle rows being removed
   $('#myTable').on('DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
      rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
      $('#rowCount').text(`Total rows: ${rowCount}`);
   });
});
```

This code listens for the `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved` events on the `#myTable` element. When those events fire (i.e. when rows are added or removed), the code updates the `rowCount` variable and displays the updated count in the `#rowCount` element.