# ("#div > tag").lenght outputing wrong value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put a counter for  items inside a  with ID
but it outputs the wrong value everytime, it actually got it right for one, but it is mere coincidence since everything else is wrong

```
<div id="foo">
<img ......>
<img ......>
<img ......>
</div>
```

There are 3  tags there. so this code

```
("#foo > img").length
```

was supposed to output "3" but it actually outputs a random number between 14 ~ 17

```
("#foo img").length
("#foo > img").length
("div#foo img").length
("div#foo > img").length
```

all these output the same wrong behaviour.

am i missing something?

Comment: `("#foo > img").length` is equivalent to `"#foo > img".length` which gets the length of the **string** `"#foo > img"`. The string has 10 characters, so the result is `10`. It seems like you intended to call a function and pass the string as selector? If so, which function did you want to call? `foo(...)` and `(...)` are two very different different things.

Comment: this might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404544/jquery-count-number-of-divs-with-a-certain-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [*Grouping Operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.6) in JavaScript is comprised of a set of parenthesis around an expression. In this case, you're using the grouping operator around a string. This returns the result of evaluating the expression, so in the case of `("Foo")`, `"Foo"` is returned.

With the grouping operator returning the string, [the `.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) being accessed is that of the string itself, which will return the size of the string itself.

Given your code, and question, it appears as though you would instead like to get the number of elements matched by a given selector. You may be looking for something like [*querySelectorAll*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
document.querySelectorAll( "#foo > img" ).length;
```

This method returns a collection of elements that match the selector. The collection will ultimately contain a `length` property, which tells you how many *elements* are contained in the collection.

Note that the above method does not return a *live* collection, meaning it will not reflect elements being added or removed *after* the method was last called.

A live collection *is returned* by other functions, such as [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName):

```
var collection = document.getElementById( "foo" ).getElementsByTagName( "img" );
```

In the above example, `collection.length` will *always* give the number of `img` elements within `#foo`, even if the total number changes after the *getElementsByTagName* function has run.