# jQuery counting items with class "checked"

Tags: jquery, css

Im struggling with this one. I have a list of items and on a part of the form when something has validated it adds class "checked" to the corresponding list item.

```
<ul>
<li class="title">Checklist</li>
<li class="checkType checked">Card Type</li>
<li class="checkNumber checked">Card Number</li>
<li class="checkName checked">Name on Card</li>
<li class="checkMonth checked">Expiry Month</li>
<li class="checkYear checked">Expiry Year</li>
<li class="checkCode checked">Security Code</li>
</ul>

.title{font-size:23px; font-weight:bold;}
.checked{ color:#f00;}
```

But I need jQuery to check that each item has the class `checked` EXCEPT `title`.

Is this doable?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bQtEQ/1/

Thanks to the answers I now have the following

```
        var counting = $("li.checked:not(.title)").length;
    if (counting == 6){
        console.log(counting);
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes, you look at the question and you wonder why there aren't 10 answers... and you wait another second... boom!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery counting elements by class what is the best way to implement this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this)

Comment: All he needs is `$(".checked").length` how  is that not a duplicate?

Comment: That doesn't discount the one with the class 'title'.  Please read the question properly.

Comment: Yes it does because he is not gonna checkmark the title element is he? Maybe the op should clarify that because it does not make sense by looking at the fiddle where it looks like the first `li` element is being used as a header of some kind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is doable with 1 simple selector

```
$("li.checked:not(.title)").length
```

The advantage here, apart from having to code less, is that the `:not()` selector is factored in during search to reduce the result set. This means less time for jQuery to instantiate dom elements. This means faster execution time, especially on older browsers.

Answer (score 8):

This should give you all of the `<li>` elements with the class '`checked`' that don't have the class title:

```
$('li.checked').not('.title').length
```

However - if you only wanted the count of the checked elements:

```
$('.checked').length
```

should suffice.

Comment: Is there an advantage doing it this way, rather than just using the selector in Ben's answer?

Comment: Adding the `li` makes it faster initially, but filtering the not after the fact slows it down. Would be interesting to benchmark for sure.

Comment: @Archer `Ben`'s answer is far more faster, because it uses [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll), which is native javascript.

Comment: @Archer - there isn't any advantage to mine. I simply threw it up there as a quick and easy answer. I actually voted up Ben's as it is a better answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.checked').not('.title').length == $("ul li").length -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").each(function() {
    if( !$(this).hasClass("title") && $(this).hasClass("checked") ) {
            alert("hah");
    }
 });
```