# jQuery: Get number of elements that have a certain class

Tags: jquery

How do I get the number of elements that have the particular class `.added` when the element with the class `.header` is clicked?

```
<ul class="main"> 
    <li class="header">Header</li>
    <li class="added">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li class="added">Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

So in this case, when I click the element with the class `.header` I would want to retrieve the number 2.

Comment: Hmmm why not just $('.added').length on .header click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`length` should work. `size()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Example:

```
$('.header').on('click', function () { 
    return $('.added').length;
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.header').on('click', function(){
  console.log($('.added').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
$('.header').on('click', function () { 
return $('.added').length;
});
```