# How to get class count on form in jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

How can i get the count of my error class on the view ?

I am adding .error class with some span and input controls.But its not necessary the all controls will show at the time of form loading or submitting.

So i just want to get count of the .error class which are showing currently on the form,with the help of jquery.

Can any one help me out on this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery counting elements by class what is the best way to implement this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this)

Comment: He's asking to count the visible elements, so it's not a duplicate of the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the number of elements that have `.error` class and are **showing currently on the form** you can do:

```
var count = $("form .error:visible").length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = $('.error').length;
```

is this what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

use **[.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)**

```
$('.error').length; //give total count of error class
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the number of the child elements you can use `.length`

You can check the length of the `.error` as

```
$('.error').length;
```

This will check for the `.error` in the body.

But to check whether they are visible or not, you can either check for their css as

```
if($(this).is(':visible')
```

Or use

```
$('.error:visible')
```

You can use this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/HVnAm/1/

http://api.jquery.com/length/