# How to get class-name of element with multiple classes but only knowing 1 of them

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get all elements that contain a class name also if the elements have multiple classes (in Javascript). For example:

```
<div class="one two three four">
<div class="one two three">
<div class="one two">
<div class="one">
```

So i now want all classes that contain the class "one". So in this case all of them. If i use getElementsByClassName i can only specify 1 class or i need to write the exact multiple classes there.

Any suggestions are really apreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get element by class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been easier (and faster) to try to write some code and test your question directly instead of asking in SO.

Or maybe reading the documentation for [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

[Sigh] you don't hace to specify the exact multiple classes. Running:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("one")
```

will give you an array with the four divs.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get the full className of every element having a class, you can do it like this

```js
// list className of all elements containing the class 'two'
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.two')).forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.className);
});
```

```html
<div class="one two three four">
<div class="one two three">
<div class="one two">
<div class="one">
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is className.

HTML

```
<div id="myId" class="one">
    stuff 
</div>
<div id="myId" class="one two">
    stuff 
</div>
```

JS

```
var d= document.getElementById('myId');
alert(d.className);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want should be 'one' , it will return all elements that have 'one' as class regardless other classes the element belongs to.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('one')
```

Just FYI for multiple classes

```
document.getElementsByClassName('one two three')
```