# Total the amount of times an HTML div is used in a PHP script?

Tags: php, css, html

I've interviewed over 40 people and I'd like to show that by saying that with a PHP script.

Each interview has its' own bunch of CSS Classes of course, and I can easily add an extra class or use one of the existing ones to discover the total amount of div's.

Here's an example of an interview:

```
  <div class="resume-item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row mb-5">
    <div class="resume-content mr-auto">
      <h3 class="mb-0">A.N. Other</h3>
      <div class="subheading mb-3">Intelligence Analysis Masters Student</div>
      <p>Interview Q&A Goes Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="resume-date text-md-right">
      <span class="text-primary">June 2017</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm thinking to use something like **PHP substr_count() Function** to achieve this...?

All the interviews are on one static HTML page.

Can someone pls point me in the right direction for this please?

Thanks!

Comment: substr_count seems perfect, whats the issue?

Comment: Javascript would be best for this. https://jsfiddle.net/s0j4ah8x/

Comment: @fyroc thanks appreciate it. Would I just place that jsfifle within script tags? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle. Just add what's in the javascript section within the script tags and then `<div id="total-count"></div>` wherever you want to display the total. If this works for you I can make it an answer. https://jsfiddle.net/s0j4ah8x/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using HTML and the HTML is already in the DOM, you're going to want to use client side (javascript) and not server side language to do this. If each person has the `resume-item` class assigned to them, use javascript to count each of those classes.

```js
// Get total of all the resume-item divs
count = document.querySelectorAll('.resume-item').length;

// Insert that total in the total-count div
document.getElementById('total-count').innerHTML = count;
```

```html
<div class="resume-item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row mb-5">
  <div class="resume-content mr-auto">
    <h3 class="mb-0">A.N. Other</h3>
    <div class="subheading mb-3">Intelligence Analysis Masters Student</div>
    <p>Interview Q&A Goes Here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resume-date text-md-right">
    <span class="text-primary">June 2017</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="resume-item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row mb-5">
  <div class="resume-content mr-auto">
    <h3 class="mb-0">A.N. Other</h3>
    <div class="subheading mb-3">Intelligence Analysis Masters Student</div>
    <p>Interview Q&A Goes Here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="resume-date text-md-right">
    <span class="text-primary">June 2017</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- put this div where you want the count to be -->
<div id="total-count"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the information in an array, so you can do a `sizeof` and get the number of interviews you've done.

### How you should store the interviews

```
<?php
$interviews = array(
  [
    'title' => 'A.N. Other',
    'subheading' => 'Intelligence Analysis Masters Student',
    'q-and-a' => 'Interview Q&A Goes Here',
    'date' => 'June 2017',
  ],
  [
    'title' => 'another entry',
    'subheading' => 'blah blah blah',
    'q-and-a' => 'blah blah blah',
    'date' => 'blah blah blah',
  ],
);
?>
```

---

### How you should display the interviews

```
<?php
foreach( $interviews as $interview ):
?>
  <div class="resume-item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row mb-5">
    <div class="resume-content mr-auto">
      <h3 class="mb-0"><?php echo $interview['title']; ?></h3>
      <div class="subheading mb-3"><?php echo $interview['subheading']; ?></div>
      <p><?php echo $interview['q-and-a']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="resume-date text-md-right">
      <span class="text-primary"><?php echo $interview['date']; ?></span>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

---

### How you display the count for the interviews

```
<?php
echo sizeof( $interviews );
?>
```

---

### Why you can't count static HTML using PHP

PHP is server-rendered. So if you were to count the amount of interviews, then you should basically crawl the page itself before you rendered the content, which would be possible, - but it would be a mess. If you insist on keeping your content as static HTML, then I would suggest using JavaScript to count the number of elements instead - for instance by giving a class to all the outer-containers for your interviews, and then doing something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727318/1766219). PHP is not suitable for this.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$subheading' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in /home/site/public_html/test.php on line 5 >>> I've tried double quotes but no joy...any idea what is missing? thanks

Comment: Yeah, - it sounds like you're trying to acces `$subheading`, when it should probably be `$interview['subheading']`. Ahhh, - wait. I forgot comma's in my solution. I've just corrected that. If you copy-paste the code, then it should work.

Comment: How did you go?